# Paper.js Resize Raster/TextItem/Path by Dragging

Tags: javascript, resize, dom-events, mouseevent, paperjs

I'm aware that I can [scale](http://paperjs.org/reference/raster/#scale-scale) a [Raster](http://paperjs.org/reference/raster/#raster) object in [Paper.js](http://paperjs.org/), as well as a [TextItem](http://paperjs.org/reference/textitem/#scale-scale) and a [Path](http://paperjs.org/reference/path/#scale-scale).

However, I'd like to do this on dragging the selection lines or bounding box of a [Raster](http://paperjs.org/reference/raster/#bounds), [TextItem](http://paperjs.org/reference/textitem/#bounds), or [Path](http://paperjs.org/reference/path/#bounds), just as you would when resizing an image in a program like Word. These bounds form a [Rectangle](http://paperjs.org/reference/rectangle/) object. Can I hook into this, perhaps using the `fitBounds` method? Or more broadly, how can I capture a mouse drag event on the selection lines of a Raster, TextItem, or Path? I suppose once I can do that I can use the `scale` method to grow/shrink the object.

Here's a Paper.js [sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#S/VZExb8IwEIX/yslSRSoVmwGWVEyIsQuMdQcTXxNDYlv2QYSq/vfaDo2EsuT53vvuOflhVg3Iana8IDUde2ON01nfVAAztLAF7ZrrgJZ4E1AR7nvMqpIsjSV7fZc2vfAYmuSVrCPytRBeeQznyF1oBV3JBaP6KMygWoxidOFibLscDXXLoCJhiGJwVvGzT8gH0egCzOeSSTvXODl958p7tHrXmV5XyZxb5EcI2JWWoGACgyEc4BrTPqAOoVQAUi3k7WD0dpE3LKTNN35ktmBxhEMR1TSfNiT+h7thIT285IpqUrWk3HdRN4OjtJODexcNGWcTNp/zyfrPOzaqfwKe7rBZvczpmOfVim/mBgdH+YbPkfUGNLYBMdZzNBRjtU7R9GNP6cNcvDOWIqs/v37/AA==) to get you started and for experimentation, borrowed from @Christoph. See also the [documentation](http://paperjs.org/reference/global/) for Paper.js.

Comment: Maybe this'll help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/26788306/826625 (working sketch included)

Comment: I am not familiar with the tech, but could you just calc the areas? For example... the draggable area should be width : 0; width: currentWidth, and the same for height. All you have to know is where the image starts, which is the x and y of the rectangle object.

Answer (score 3):

Building the actual implementation would be bothersome, but here is a POC
https://jsfiddle.net/f8h3j7v4/

```
c.addEventListener('mousedown',function(e){//c = context, check the fiddle
//Calculate the position of the edges, currently hardcoded values for fiddle
//For example getPosition(c).y + y * scaleY
//I should mention that rotate starts at the top left corner; 
//the whole canvas gets rotated(+transform exists)
//There is actually a pretty clever way to handle rotation;
//rotate the mouse position
if(e.clientY > 15 && e.clientY < 25)
    dragNorth = true
else
    dragNorth = false
if(e.clientX > 15 && e.clientX < 25)
    dragWest = true
else
    dragWest = false
if(e.clientX > 165 && e.clientX < 175)
    dragEast = true
else
    dragEast = false
if(e.clientY > 165 && e.clientY < 175)
    dragSouth = true
else
    dragSouth = false
})

function getPosition(element) {
var xPosition = 0;
var yPosition = 0;

while(element) {
    xPosition += (element.offsetLeft - element.scrollLeft + element.clientLeft);
    yPosition += (element.offsetTop - element.scrollTop + element.clientTop);
    element = element.offsetParent;
}
return { x: xPosition, y: yPosition };
}
//Thanks to  
//http://www.kirupa.com/html5/get_element_position_using_javascript.htm
```

Just calc the position of the canvas and then drag away :)

Comment: How are the numbers here chosen?

Comment: Check out the fiddle, in theory you should calc the numbers yourself(that's the implementation part, the hardest part is calculating for rotation, but I think there is a func for that)