# How to add text input selector and dragable using paper.js?

Tags: canvas, text, paperjs

Is it possible to add point text to at mouse pointed position and can we change that text and position using PAPER.JS?

like this screen
[image]

I did not find any documentation correctly. Please, anyone, suggest how can we do this?

Answer (score 0):

The description of what you are trying to do is maybe a bit short but here is a first step showing how to draw a point text at mouse position: [sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.12.7/S/dVC9zsIwDHwVKwsgCmJEZYQV6ZNgA4YQjBr6YaPEbUCo705SoLBgKZF/zncn3xXpM6pcrUoUU6hMGT6k+liREcsETEuuPC44UB9rJBnAfeu2BDEIA/yxJVnjVfpdO8UltXNoN8ZtkX2PDZNgAvSWN5C43XtPm8EspU360vuh8SGY/1tTguczhgIdRsMgBYLRVGsPwnBwOoB+qnQmXv5qi2FsIhE6GMJmksFoOtl1qFPlxR6t0ekUUeuJbL2+fMaL7R3qsuXzKt/smgc=)
You should be able to adapt it to your own use case.

```
function onMouseDown(event) {
    new PointText({
        point: event.point,
        content: 'My text'
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am trying to add handle bar like my attachment. Is it possible on paper js?

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to do that in Paper.js, you would have to implement it yourself. It is doable, [as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26785966/transform-bounding-box-in-paper-js).

You can also consider [Konvas](https://konvajs.org/docs/sandbox/Canvas_Editor.html) which implements such feature.